# Set Opacity with UI Slider on Leaflet _leaflet_id

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Using jquery UI, I have a slider setup passing in decimal numbers "0.1" to "0.9" in order to change the opacity of the current layer on the map.

I am able to get the current layer ID, but cannot figure out how to change the opacity at this point.

Using activeLayers plugin:

```
var overlayLayers = activeControl.getActiveOverlayLayers();
```

overlayLayers returns the current opacity correctly:

```
for (var overlayId in overlayLayers) {
    var lOpacity = overlayLayers[overlayId].layer.options.opacity;
    console.log(lOpacity);
}
```

I have seen a few posts where folks are using setOpacity on the layer var, but not the layer ID.

Can you not set opacity on layer id like:

```
lOpacity.setOpactiy(value);
```

or

```
overlayLayers[overlayId].layer.options.opacity="0.5";
```

What am I missing?